# How to recursively search for directory by name and delete all regular files in it

Tags: files, find

I'm working on a bash script in an AWS EC2 instance (RHEL derived) which needs to do the following:

1. Search for all directories named `"_combined"` in `${PROJECT_DIR}`
2. Delete all regular files in all those directories - but not the directory itself

What's the best approach to do this?

Comment: @don_crissti - good point. I meant regular files, will amend question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, something like

```
find "$PROJECT_DIR" -path "*/_combined/*" -type f
```

And if that seems right:

```
find "$PROJECT_DIR" -path "*/_combined/*" -type f -delete
```

Of course that will hit all regular files in the whole tree, not just immediate contents of `_combined`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you've described. When you are *sure* it works, replace the `-print` clause with `-delete`:

```
find "$PROJECT_DIR" -type d -name '_combined' -execdir find '_combined' -maxdepth 1 -type f -print \;
```

What it does is to search for all directories named `_combined` underneath `$PROJECT_DIR`, and in each one it runs the second `find` snippet which will remove all non-directories in the found directory.